# Image disappears in animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image

I am creating an animation where my image will translate to a different spot on the screen and then fade in gradually. I completed the translation part(see below) but now when I start the fade in animation it disappears for the duration and then reapears after. I want to show the image being faded in gradually....Any ideas why this is happening?

```
public static int moveTwo(AnimationListener activity, View apa, int animationmove)


Log.v("MOVETWO", "Started move2");
AnimationSet picMov2 = new AnimationSet(true);
picMov2.setAnimationListener(activity);
RotateAnimation rotate2 = new RotateAnimation(0, 0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f);
// rotate1.setStartOffset(50);
rotate2.setDuration(2000);
picMov2.addAnimation(rotate2);
TranslateAnimation trans2 = new TranslateAnimation(-200, -400, 0, 0);
trans2.setDuration(2000);
picMov2.setFillAfter(true);
picMov2.addAnimation(trans2);
apa.startAnimation(picMov2);
animationmove = 3;
return animationmove;





public static int moveThree(AnimationListener activity, View apa, int animationmove)


AlphaAnimation fadein = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.3, 1);//HERE THE IMAGE IS DISAPPEARING
fadein.setAnimationListener(activity);

fadein.setDuration(2000);
fadein.setFillAfter(true);
apa.startAnimation(fadein);
animationmove=4;
return animationmove;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just needed to create a translate action in the same place so it doesn't go back to its original position

```
public static int moveThree(AnimationListener activity, View apa, int animationmove)
{
    Log.v("MOVETHREE", "Started move3");

    AnimationSet picMov3 = new AnimationSet(true);
    picMov3.setAnimationListener(activity);
    AlphaAnimation fadein = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.4, 1);
    // rotate1.setStartOffset(50);
    fadein.setDuration(duration);
    picMov3.addAnimation(fadein);
    TranslateAnimation trans1 = new TranslateAnimation(-400, -400, 0, 0);
    trans1.setDuration(duration);
    picMov3.setFillAfter(true);
    picMov3.addAnimation(trans1);
    apa.startAnimation(picMov3);
```

Comment: the answer does not explain any thing, it is hard to relate between the answer and the question !!!